# Objective-C: Multidimensional array as a parameter

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing

i try to pass a multidimensional array as a parameter to a method. in this method the reference to the array should be stored in another variable. this all seems to work, but when i try to access the array through my new variable there is a error.

this is my code:

```
-(void)renderMap:(char[MAP_HEIGHT][MAP_WIDTH])mapData {
        char* data;
        data = *mapData;
        NSLog(@"%c", data[1][1]); // Subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
char (*data)[MAP_WIDTH] = mapData
NSLog(@"%c", data[1][1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer directly via `mapData`, without `data = *mapData`.

Comment: thanks - i know this would work, but i need the reference because later it will be a private object variable - which i use in other methods

Comment: So just write `data = mapData`. Unless your map data won't be removed from memory, the reference in `data` will be still valid and the array will be accessible.

Comment: when i write data = mapData there is a warning:
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'char' from char(*)[30]

Comment: You should declare your private field as `char **data;`.

Comment: this seems to be the right way. but i still got a warning in the data = mapData line: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'char**' from char(*)[30]

Comment: Even if you wouldn't have a syntax error, this wouldn't work because an array is not a double pointer. Once you declare data as a double pointer and try to access to the array elements, every data[i] will be considered a pointer, which it isn't.

Answer (score -1):

`mapData` is not a bidimensional array, so you can't use the double brackets. You have to access to every element by calculating the offset of each element's row:

```
NSLog(@"%c",data[1*MAP_HEIGHT+1]);
// Generic way:
NSLog(@"%c",data[row*MAP_HEIGHT+column]);
```